# How to raised the tiles-size by a docker openmaptiles-server

Tags: maptiler, openmaptiles

I use to docker version from https://openmaptiles.com. and its run fine, but I like to raised to size of an raster-tiles. Which I get from a GetMap WMS request. so I can get a 10000px x10000px Tiles.

Thanks for helping. :D

Comment: What is the reason for wanting tiles of that size? This feels like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

In the OpenMapTiles Server (https://openmaptiles.com/server/) wizard under Advanced options you have a possibility to set the maximal size for Static Maps API under:

Maximum image size (including scale factor).

The default value is 2048, you can set in the wizard 4096 pixels (which is an internal limit of the xvfb).

The larger requests should be probably composed of multiple "tiles" on the client side... or via a proxy.

If you need help with setup you can get our https://openmaptiles.com/support/